# How to pass the parse objects to my list in the fragments?

Tags: android

I have 2 fragments in tablayout, which must be filled in according to the user of the parse database.

But I am facing a problem to take the list, it follows the code of MainActivity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Parse.initialize(this);
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        .......

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Items");
        // this will find the user.
        // then find the first instance
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                List<Items> 1List = new ArrayList<Items>();
                List<Items> 2List = new ArrayList<Items>();
                if (objects == null) {
                    Log.d("nothing found", "let's go ahead and create a new object.");
                    //ADD THE OBJECT AS A NEW OBJECT!!!!
                } else {
                    for(i=0;objects.size() > 0;i++) {
                        ParseObject parseObject = objects.get(i);
                        if(parseObject.getString("iduser").equals(ID_1)){

                            1List.add(objects.get(i));//ERROR HOW TO FIX?
                            /*THIS ERROR add
                            (com.dev.bob.recife3.persistence.Items)
                                    in List cannot be applied
                                    to
                            (com.parse.ParseObject)*/

                        }else{
                            2List.add(objects.get(i));//ERROR HOW TO FIX?
                            /*THIS ERROR add
                            (com.dev.bob.recife3.persistence.Items)
                                    in List cannot be applied
                                    to
                            (com.parse.ParseObject)*/
                        }
                        if (getFragmentRefreshListener1() != null) {
                            getFragmentRefreshListener1().onRefresh(new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), 1List));
                        }

                        if (getFragmentRefreshListener2() != null) {
                            getFragmentRefreshListener2().onRefresh(new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), 2List));
                        }
                        String test = parseObject.getString("name").toString();//JUST A TEST
                        Log.d("points found", "" + "");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    ........
    public class SectionPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionPagerAdapter(FragmentM2ger fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new 2TabFragment();
                case 1:
                    return new 1TabFragment();
                default:
                    return new 2TabFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }//retorna as duas abas estaticamente

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.2);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.1);
                default:
                    return getString(R.string.2);
            }
        }
    }
    private Context getContext(){
        return this;
    }

    public FragmentRefreshListener getFragmentRefreshListener1() {
        return fragmentRefreshListener1;
    }

    public void setFragmentRefreshListener1(FragmentRefreshListener fragmentRefreshListener1) {
        this.fragmentRefreshListener1 = fragmentRefreshListener1;
    }

    private FragmentRefreshListener fragmentRefreshListener1;

    public interface FragmentRefreshListener{
        void onRefresh(ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter);
    }


    public FragmentRefreshListener2 getFragmentRefreshListener2() {
        return fragmentRefreshListener2;
    }

    public void setFragmentRefreshListener2(FragmentRefreshListener2 fragmentRefreshListener2) {
        this.fragmentRefreshListener2 = fragmentRefreshListener2;
    }

    private FragmentRefreshListener2 fragmentRefreshListener2;

    public interface FragmentRefreshListener2{
        void onRefresh(ItemsAdapter itemsAdapter);
    }
}
```

How do I get to fragments, the list that arrives from parse?
How do I get this data passed and this list appear in the correct fragment? The error is commented out in the code, this is:

> 1List.add (objects.get (i)); 
>                                    
>                                    (com.dev.bob.recife3.persistence.Items)
>                                            in List can not be applied
>                                            to
>                                    (com.parse.ParseObject)

Follows image of the database:
[image]

Comment: It's probably because your list is a list of Items and you're trying to put in an instance of ParseObject.

Comment: I changed my adapter to receive a parseobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my adapter to receive parseobject:

```
List<ParseObject> 1List= new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
if (getFragmentRefreshListener1() != null) {
                            getFragmentRefreshListener1().onRefresh(new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), 1List));
                        }

                        if (getFragmentRefreshListener2() != null) {
                            getFragmentRefreshListener2().onRefresh(new ItemsAdapter(getContext(), 2List));
                        }
```

And my ItemsAdapter:

```
public ItemsAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> items) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsList = items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your query from generic `ParseObject` into `Items` like this.

```
ParseQuery<Items> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(Items.class);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Items>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<Items> objects, com.parse.ParseException e) {
    }
});
```

That could fix the crash. For how to pass the data into your fragments. That can come up later if you fixed crash first.

Comment: It does not work, the type of the incoming object is of type parseobject

Comment: I changed my adapter to receive a parseobject

Comment: Did you declare the `Items` class extend from ParseObject? Because normally that's how parse query a specify table and parser into a custom Parseobject instance.

Comment: No, I'm not, now I changed my adapter to receive parseobject. internally, in class, I get what I need. Your response gave me that path to solve.